# How to resolve the error : sqlite3 database is locked in iPhone.

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

When I debug the code, it gives me the following error : **sqlite3_step** return **error 21** after closing database.
And after that, when I want to do operations such as insert or update, I receive this error  : Database is locked.

What does this error indicate and how to solve this error ?
If any one has an idea about it then guide me on what's going wrong here.

Comment: "Database is locked" means that there is still some active transaction. To avoid this error, fix the bugs in your code.

Comment: how to know which transaction active or not active. @CL.

Comment: How should anybode else know how your code handles transactions and connections?

Answer (score 0):

According to me integrating SQLite inside Objective-C you have to have a bridge or wrapper either from your own or from some third party like [FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb). Your question is too abstract and it depends on how you have implemented the data retrieval logic.

`SQLITE_MISUSE` which is 21 and you can refer the whole list [here](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/c_abort.html). Most properly your are misusing ;) the SQLite. If your are new to SQLite and Objective-C better use some libraries to communicate your database.

Comment: You can use SQLite "straight" from Objective-C -- no need for a "wrapper" (though they are often used).

Answer (score -1):

For this you have to proper open and close the database.If database is already open and you are trying to open it then it will get locked.

Comment: Open it and leave it open, until the app shuts down.  And opening a second time will not cause the error -- it's due to starting a second transaction while one is still in flight.

Comment: Exactly that I want to say if NO use then close database after first operation and again open if you want to start second transaction.

Comment: No, leave the DB open, unless you only use it sporadically.  There is no need to open and close the DB for each transaction.

Comment: When i open the database  it's start with multithreded. thread_safe() sqlite function gives me after close database returns 2. how to open & close database perfectly using single thread? when close the database thread also be suspended. is it possible? @HotLicks

Comment: Regardless of how you open the database, or how threading mode is configured, if you are multithreading you need to use an external mutex to assure that only one transaction is attempted at a time.  Yes, SQLite may be configured to detect concurrent access, but getting "database locked" halfway through your operation is messy to recover from.